# offsetHeight not working properly in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, height

I come across a funny problem. I don't know the what could be the reason. I tried to search on internet but no solutions I got. The problem is offsetWidth is working perfect in Chrome but offsetHeight is not working properly. Sometime it returns the value but sometime not. May I know is there any solution to sort out this issue.

Note: I have tried to use id.height, id.clientHeight. But all are giving me the same problem. In my projects we use Prototype and JQuery also.

I have used prototype getHeight() also.. but not working in Chrome. getWidth() is working perfect. But all these are working well in Firefox... :(

**This is the code block**

```
$('leftImage_<?php echo $iExtLoop; ?>').style.position="relative";
$('leftImage_<?php echo $iExtLoop; ?>').style.left= ($('leftImageDiv').offsetWidth - $('leftImage_<?php echo $iExtLoop; ?>').offsetWidth)/2 + "px";
$('leftImage_<?php echo $iExtLoop; ?>').style.top= ($('leftImageDiv').offsetHeight - $('leftImage_<?php echo $iExtLoop; ?>').offsetHeight)/2 + "px";

if($('stripLeft_<?php echo $iExtLoop; ?>')){
    $('stripLeft_<?php echo $iExtLoop; ?>').style.position="relative";
    $('stripLeft_<?php echo $iExtLoop; ?>').style.left= ($('leftImageDiv').offsetWidth - $('stripLeft_<?php echo $iExtLoop; ?>').offsetWidth) + "px";
    $('stripLeft_<?php echo $iExtLoop; ?>').style.top= ($('leftImageDiv').offsetHeight - $('stripLeft_<?php echo $iExtLoop; ?>').offsetHeight) + "px";                                      
}
```

---

Refactored code, added by Šime Vidas:

```
var img = $( 'leftImage_<?php echo $iExtLoop; ?>' );
var div = $( 'leftImageDiv' );
var strip = $( 'stripLeft_<?php echo $iExtLoop; ?>' );

img.style.position = "relative";
img.style.left = ( div.offsetWidth - img.offsetWidth ) / 2 + "px";
img.style.top = ( div.offsetHeight - img.offsetHeight ) / 2 + "px";

if ( strip ) {
    strip.style.position = "relative";
    strip.style.left = ( div.offsetWidth - strip.offsetWidth ) + "px";
    strip.style.top= ( div.offsetHeight - strip.offsetHeight ) + "px";
}
```

Comment: code block added... any ideas why it is??

Comment: What's the `$`? Prototype or jQuery?

Comment: @FaizulHasan For crying out loud, cache those references. I've added the improved code to your question...

Comment: "Sometime it returns the value but sometime not." < Do you use some kind of "onload" event handler to run your JavaScript?

Comment: In your code, you're reading the `offsetHeight` of three different elements. Are all three values incorrect?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: For div it is returning correct value. But for img it is not returning correct value sometime...

Comment: @Oleg: I tried with onload. But no changes...

Comment: @FaizulHasan Onload should work. How exactly have you tried it?

Comment: Could you post the code you used in your onload attempt? The "not working sometimes" is a usual symptom of an onload problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since at least one of the elements appears to be an IMG element, I'm guessing that the element has not finished loading by the time that code is executed.

Images have to be retrieved separately (by the browser), so you have to make sure that you read their height only after they've finished loading.

Comment: Sorry for confusing. onload is not working in the sense, the image width and height are correctly calculated. But its style is not getting set to that image.

It means: 
strip.style.position = "relative";
    strip.style.left = ( div.offsetWidth - strip.offsetWidth ) + "px";
    strip.style.top= ( div.offsetHeight - strip.offsetHeight ) + "px";

this part of code block is not executed or something. But the image is not positioned to the required place

Comment: @FaizulHasan Set a break-point on that line and see if it executes. If yes, see what values are assigned.